# Asp.net bootstrap carousel slider does not work

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I been trying to follow a tutorial and implement the bootstrap carousel slider. I want to use it later in my own webpage, but for know i'm just trying to get it work.

Right now it doesn't showing anything in the asp.net webform i have create in Visual Studio. I'm not sure what is wrong, because the code is the same.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Fullslider</title>

     <link href="Content/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="Script/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="Script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </header>

           <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000 //changes the speed
        })
</script>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

The code have the standard bootstrap navigation bar which works perfect.. but there is just empty space where the carousel should be.

Can any see what is wrong?

**CSS file:**

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Full Slider HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you included `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` twice?

Comment: I'm pretty new.. so it was just something i tried to make it work

Comment: You want full page slider?? I mean slide which shows as body background??

Comment: It was just the toturial i followed.. i just want it to work because then i can make the rest on my own.. but can't see what is wrong, i'm not that experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I just saw some different codes may be because of which it might not have worked!

Below are the possible reasons which might be the reason why it did not work:

> - You were using **<kbd>`<header>`</kbd>** instead of **<kbd>`div`</kbd>**
> - Basically you were using **<kbd>`<div>`</kbd>** instead of **<kbd>`<img>`</kbd>** and you used to set the `background-image` of that **<kbd>`<div>`</kbd>** and for `caption` you had one more **<kbd>`div`</kbd>**.
> - You had some extra classes added to your **<kbd>`<div>`</kbd>** which had its own styles which would have effected its original styles
> - Overall it was working in background but its height was getting effected

See this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rtfy5r31/1/)** with the basic and initial design of carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One" alt="Chania"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two" alt="Chania"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three" alt="Flower"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two" alt="Flower"/>
            </div>
      </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, For me issue is change to div to image like:  <img class="fill" src="images/img1.jpg"/>. @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: @zahed.. Glad it helped.. Happy coding.. :)